# ASP.NET Configuring Membership User Requirements

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

I am following MSDN's walkthrough on [Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx).

I have completed the **Configuring Membership** section, and I just tested it out.

The username and password requirements are more strict than our company requires, so I need to know where to go in to set those requirements.

The current error is:

**Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1.**

Where do I set these requirements?

[image: Password length minimum Non-alphanumeric characters required]

**EDIT:**

Below is the default `Web.config` file that Microsoft creates whenever I created this web application.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Somehow, there is a database connection string in all of that, but I certainly do not see it.

My ASP.NET Provider is `AspNetSqlProvider` and the Test is successful ...but I do not know where this database is. I do not see it in my project.

[image: AspNetSqlProvider Screenshot]

Comment: FYI: [Link 169433] (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433) takes you to a whole online book about ASP.net that is covered in links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be set in the `web.config` of your web application ...

```
<membership>
   <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="connName"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="5" /><!-- set password length here -->
   </providers>
  </membership>
```

Comment: So, setting this value in the `Web.config` of my Visual Studio project will be used whenever I debug my web app through `localhost`? [Still a Noobie. I am not comfortable yet with how a config file in a test project is changing how the `localhost` operates during debug.]

Comment: This configures the out-of-box `SqlMembershipProvider` with the appropriate settings...

Comment: Where would I find my `connectionStringName` value?

Comment: Under the `connectionStrings` element in the web.config file - this should be the DB that the `aspnet` schema is installed on...

Comment: My `Web.config` file (before I started this) was nearly empty. It had `<configuration><system.web><roleManager enabled="true" /></system.web></configuration>` That was it. How was it connecting to **anything** before???